# Rewrite url parameter to folder with htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

i would like to rewrite all my website's urls from this
https://website.com/page.php?lang=2 to this 
https://website.com/en/page

(creating /en/ directory while hiding .php extension)

Can anyone help me with this one?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: In the above link the .php extension is not hidden

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^en/([\w-]+)$ $1.php?lang=2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Although it seems to work, something is wrong about the relative paths to the css. The page is loading broken with the following errors in the console: "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/htm"l and "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

Comment: Try <base href="your domain.com/"> in your page where css is not loading, change your domain to actual domain name.